# How to integrate MongoMock with Pymongo-Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mocking, pytest

I'd like to write some unit tests of our mongo code using mongomock as the backend. However, Flask-PyMongo adds a convenience class (`find_one_or_404`) on top of the Collection class that means that I can't do a straight-up MongoMock substitution. Any attempts at monkeypatching this function onto the Collection class don't seem to be working (I assume it has something to do with the overridden `__getattr__` - every time I try I get `TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable` on `db.collection_name.find_one_or_404({})`). What are my options here, besides just not using this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was "mocks all the way down" in absentia of a better idea

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_thing_collection(mocker):
  mock_data = Mock()
  mock_db = Mock()
  mock_db.things = mock_data
  mock = mocker.patch("app.mongo")
  mock.db = mock_db
  return mock_data
```

and then, in the test

```
def test_things(mocker, client, mock_thing_collection):
  return_items = ["a", "b", "c"]
  find_mock = mocker.patch.object(mock_thing_collection, 'find', return_value=return_items)
```

Comment: so you didn't manage to use mongomock at all? because I am using it with Django and it is great!